# Tight Chernoff Concentration for Bernoulli(p) RV

Tags: pr.probability, st.statistics, measure-concentration

I remember seeing a research paper on tight concentration of Bernoulli(p) random variable in terms of $p$.
What I mean is that they used a stronger upper bound for the MGF than $E[e^{s(X-p)
}]\leq e^{s^2/8}$.
However, I can't find this work. Can someone please point me to it?

In particular, we know the exact MGF of $E[e^{s(X-p)
}]$
and they used this in the standard Chernoff bound instead to get a tail bound that depends on $p$.

The reason why I want this is because when $p=0$ or $p=1$, there is no variance and we should expect tighter bound. I know that I can use Bernstein's bound with variance as $p(1-p)$ but I was wondering if there is anything else I can use.

Comment: Kearns-Saul inequality

https://cstheory.stackexchange.com/questions/32978/orlicz-norm-of-random-variable-and-variance/33008#33008